# Mongodb Client-Side Field Level Encryption (CSFLE) :fatal error: mongocrypt.h not found

Tags: mongodb, go, encryption

I'm trying to implement the MongoDB client-side field-level encryption in Go. When I try to run the project, I'm getting the below error.

```
sudo go build -tags cse main.go
```

*# go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/mongocrypt
../../go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.0/x/mongo/driver/mongocrypt/binary.go:11:11: fatal error: mongocrypt.h: No such file or directory
// #include <mongocrypt.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.*

I followed the steps mentioned in [this](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.0-beta2.0.20201111202951-cdacb6473abf/mongo#hdr-Client_Side_Encryption) tutorial.
Installed [libmongocrypt](https://github.com/mongodb/libmongocrypt#installing-libmongocrypt-from-distribution-packages)

MongoDB Version used:4.4 enterprise edition.
OS: Ubuntu 18.4
go version:1.15
Please help me to resolve this issue.